# Eclipse/PHP: PDO cannot be resolved as a type

Tags: pdo, eclipse-pdt

i like to convert a old PHP Project from PHP 5.1 to PHP 7.2. I changed in the project settings the PHP Version (Project/Properties/PHP/Validation) to 7.2. The Project was rebuild.

I added new PHP Code:

```
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

A red x at the side displays: "PDO cannot be resolved as a type"
How can i remove or IGNORE this kind of error?

Thanks!

Comment: If this code is in a namespace, you may want to try `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` to ensure it is looking in the right place.

Comment: Thanks, it wont work. Do i need to install PDO for PHP?

Comment: Did you also configure the corresponding PHP 7.2 executable in _Window > Preferences: PHP > Installed PHPs_?

Comment: Installed PHPs is empty, the subfolder execution environments shows php version 7.2. What i need to configure?

Comment: Without the installed PHP, Eclipse cannot resolve `PDO` and does not know what it is. And without knowing what it is, syntax checking, navigation, etc. are not possible. It does not make sense to use a PHP editor without specifying the installed PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Necro but never completely answered: "How to remove or Ignore..."

In addition to howlger's answers, also "use PDO;" along with any needed specific namespace declaration.  (op references project as 5.1, namespace 5.3, I believe.)